# Why is greedy algorithm not finding maximum independent set of a bipartite graph?

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-theory

I was trying to solve the maximum independent set problem on bipartite graphs using the greedy method. So came across this post which does exactly what i was trying to do. But am concentrating only on the bipartite graphs. The counter case in the answer is not a bipartite graph. Are there any bipartite graphs that this one wont work?

```
Greedy(G):
 S = {}
 While G is not empty:
 Let v be a node with minimum degree in G
 S = union(S, {v})
 remove v and its neighbors from G
return S
```

[Why is greedy algorithm not finding maximum independent set of a graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921679/why-is-greedy-algorithm-not-finding-maximum-independent-set-of-a-graph)

Comment: Please quote the algorithm here. Interesting question, though.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The same approach as in [the original question answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13921679/why-is-greedy-algorithm-not-finding-maximum-independent-set-of-a-graph) applies here as well, with a slightly modified graph:

[image: (2,2,4)theta 7-vertex bipartite graph]

Start by removing #5, What's left is a paw graph (nodes (1,3,4,7)). Remove its leaves in any order. You discover a four-node independent set: (1,3,5,7)

Start by removing #6. What's left is a 4-cycle. Removing any node forces either of these sets:

1. (1,3,6)
2. (2,4,6)

both are three-element maximal (as in, cannot be expanded) independent sets, and thus not maximum (as in, the largest possible).

Comment: Now, finding a graph where this algorithm is _forced_ to make a mistake is an interesting task. I don't know about one, though

Comment: @j_random_hacker adding (5, 4) and (7, 2) doesn't force the choice of 6, you can still choose 1 or 3. The smallest graph where the greedy algorithm is forced to fail is https://pasteboard.co/8Ni6WmJXXEAZ.png

Comment: @meblum: You're right, thanks. I've removed by comment.